# How do I get the Piece of Heart in the Sanctuary underground path?

Tags: zelda-link-between-worlds

One of the first places you visit is an underground path between the graveyard and the Sanctuary, and there is a Piece of Heart in there that you can't seem to reach. Is there a way to get it then, or do I have to come back later with a specific item or ability to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first dungeon, you get the power to merge with walls.  Start from the nearby chest on the upper level, merge with the wall, and stroll over to claim your heart piece.